# Migrating from SVN to Git when using Visual Studio - adjusting the workflow

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, version-control, workflow

We have got to a point where SVN does not support our workflow.

Currently we have a SVN trunk where developers commit everything to our central server (which has RAID and gets backed-up regularly) at least once a day. When a developer thinks that the feature is ready, our SVN maintainer merges the code into the stable branch, which then gets regularly built and deployed on our test servers. 
We have also some feature branches but they generally are not a problem because they get reintegrated into the trunk only at the very end of the feature development.

The main problem is the trunk. It has a high chance to become chaotic because of daily commits. No-one can guarantee that at the end of day every developer will have a code that does not break something for other developers. You could say - if it does not work then don't commit it, but then we risk to lose a day of work in case of PC or hard drive failures. We could create a separate branch for each developer but managing and merging those branches is not a trivial process on SVN, especially because some developers are beginners (we take some trainees from our local university). And some features have just a day or two of development time, so it is not worth the hassle to create a dedicated branch on SVN.

When looking for tools to simplify our workflow, I remembered my experience with TFS shelvesets. They seemed really useful for storing unfinished changes on the remote server. But shelvesets do not support versioning, which might be a problem if a developer needs to revert to some earlier code. Also moving to TFS is not an option for us because our servers are Linux based, although our developers are mainly using Windows with Visual Studio.

Then I started exploring Git. It seems really powerful, and also there are some extensions for Visual Studio emerging lately. But I'm a bit confused about how it will work out. It seems that Git offers local clones of repository which is nice, but still we need to push the local changes to the central server quite often to avoid data loss.

What we essentially need, is ability for developers to "automagically" work on their own branch (fully featured, with versioning etc.) which is stored on the central server to avoid data loss in case some developer's PC fails. Each developer gets his own branch by default (and he/she should be able to fork a branch off his/her "master" branch for some experiments), but developers should not be permitted to push changes from their branches directly into the Git master branch. Only the person responsible for maintaining the master branch will be allowed to merge-in the features from developer "master" branches.

**Will it be possible to achieve such workflow with Git by default or do we need some additional tools or settings?
Could Git offer a better workflow which essentially lets us achieve the same goal - minimize risk of data loss caused by working on detached local copies and minimize chaos caused by pushing daily changes to our central repository?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface**

Bad workflow (and poor usage of current SCM) is bad reason for changing SCM

**Face**

Yes, Git *can* (theoretically) help minimize risk of data losses and risk of chaos

- Each developer have local repository and at least two remotes: personal remote repo and common Central repo
- Because each developer work in own repo, he can't destroy other's work

But Git, due to

- DVCS nature
- overall complexity

bring a lot of additional headaches:

- managing ACLs for branches in "central" repo is big heavy not-obvious task
- DVCS means you can't effectively manage **every** repository (and Information Security)
- "Beginners", which have problems with ordinary daily-usage of Subversion, will have a **lot more troubles** with Git
- Git in Windows is still "pour cousin" with a heap of platform-specific issues and problems

**Resume**

I'll suggest streamline your workflow, fix (bad) habits and continue to work in Subversion at least some time.

I.e

- Start using "Branch per Task" workflow, don't commit into trunk directly - trunk must (ideally) contain *only mergesets*
- Follow **strictly** main VCS-rule "Commit often, commit fast" - one giant commit per day is terrible idea. Commit must contain 1) single 2) logically independent 3) manageable block of changes
- Move to Subversion 1.8 - which made development  (move as first-class citizen, improved merge) and management of repositories (inherited properties, RDC) in some critical aspects a lot easier

Comment: Thank you for your insight. We have no problems with "Commit often, commit fast". Our problem is that most of the commits are work-in-progress, and developers are too lazy to create a new branch for every single feature they do. I guess, we'll try to find a way to make our trunk unavailable for direct commits, thus forcing devs to create their own branches.

Comment: @Martin - I was confused by phrase " commit everything to our central server at least once a day": I can't count my WIP-commits per day. Trunk **must be available** for commits (because commit of mergeset is **commit** also). Preventing *unneeded commits* into trunk is task for pre-commit hook a) You can test changing mergeinfo of trunk and disable commit, if it was not changed b) if merges to trunk allowed only to known "Merge-Masters", you can in hook use `svnlook dirs-changed` and `svnlook author` pair of commands: if dirs-changed contain /trunk and author isn't mergemaster - disable commit